# How to convert my MySQL query to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

How to write this MySQL query to Laravel's Eloquent?

```
SELECT
  products.pro_code               AS code,
  products.name               AS product,
  sum(ppurchases.quantity)    AS total_quantity,
  products.reorder_point      AS reorder_point,
  products.selling_price      AS selling_price,
  min(ppurchases.expiry_date) AS nearest_expiry
FROM `ppurchases`
  JOIN `products`
WHERE ppurchases.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY products.name
```

[image: This is how it looks like on mysql query]

I am writing it as following but unable to succeed.

```
$products = DB::table('products')
                ->JOIN('ppurchases','ppurchases.product_id', '=','products.id')
                ->select('products.pro_code as code','products.name as product','products.reorder_point as reorder_point','products.selling_price as selling_price',DB::raw('min(ppurchases.expiry_date) as nearest_expiry'))
                ->where('ppurchases.product_id','products.id')
                ->groupBy('products.name')
                ->get();
```

[image: This is an error i am getting with my eloquent code]

Comment: do you have eloquent models set up? If not, look int raw expressions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Without any attempt at this work, the question can be closed as "too broad". From the official close reasons: _Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer_.

Comment: added my parts of code,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use per prefix as you are using Raw

```
$products = DB::table('products')
    ->join('ppurchases', 'ppurchases.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->select(
        'products.name as product',
        DB::raw('min(per_ppurchases.expiry_date) as nearest_expiry')
    )
    ->groupBy('products.name')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: updating to the new table names.

I was getting nonaggregated column errors because of the default Homestead  sql_mode=only_full_group_by flag. Adding the 2 addition MAX (you can replace with MIN(), or AVG() seemed to do the trick.

```
$result = DB::table('per_ppurchases')
    ->join('per_products', 'per_ppurchases.product_id', '=', 'per_products.id')
    ->select(
        'per_products.name                       as code',
        'per_products.name                       as product',
        DB::raw('SUM(per_ppurchases.quantity)    as total_quantity'),
        DB::raw('MAX(per_products.reorder_point) as reorder_point'),
        DB::raw('MAX(per_products.selling_price) as selling_price'),
        DB::raw('MIN(per_ppurchases.expiry_date) as nearest_expiry')
    )
    ->groupBy('per_products.name')
    ->get();
```